# Pegasus UnlockPICImagXpress.PS_Unlock(000,111,222,333);

Tags: asp.net, leadtools-sdk

I have to do a migration for some projects which use Pegasus and they are made in .Net. They have a reference to PegasusImaging.WinForms.ImagXpress7.dll. In one of those project I found this line of code

```
UnlockPICImagXpress.PS_Unlock(000,111,222,333)
```

My question is if any of you know what it does, and what should be the equivalent line of code using Leadtools?

Answer (score 0):

Migrating an existing application to make use of the vast wealth of LEADTOOLS classes and functions should not be thought of as translating individual lines of code. Instead, you must determine what features and functionality your application needs then use the appropriate LEADTOOLS functions to implement these features.

Having said that, this particular line of code appears to be related to licensing, and you probably should not be publishing the numbers passed to this method in case they happen to be customer-specific license codes. If this is indeed license-unlocking code, the equivalent in LEADTOOLS would be the `Leadtools.RasterSupport.SetLicense()` method. For more details about it, see the [Add References and Set a License C# tutorial](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/dotnet-console-add-references-and-set-a-license.html).

If you need more details about setting the LEADTOOLS license or using any specific toolkit features, send full details along with your LEADTOOLS SDK serial number to support@leadtools.com

Comment: I will follow your advice. The problem with Pegasus is that there is almost no documentation about it on Internet . The accusoft page has been a big help to understand better the Pegasus code. Thank you.